# How to split list into subsist and then average it in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, sublist

I wrote the following code, that takes 10 samples then splits it into two lists and then average it, i.e. in the output I have 5 data samples.

```
av = 2
data = np.random.randn(10);
print(data)
tic = time.time();
def average(av_n, data):
    if av_n > 1:
        data = data[:len(data) - len(data) % av_n];
        llen = len(data)
        avedDataLen = int(llen/av_n);
        chunks = [data[x:x+avedDataLen] for x in xrange(0, llen, avedDataLen)]
        print (chunks)
        def divide(x): return (x / av_n)
        return map(divide, map(sum, zip(*chunks)))
    else:
        return data

amp = np.asarray(average(av, data))
print(amp)
print ('takes time: ' +str(time.time() - tic))
```

For example my input is:

```
[-0.22609503 -0.4501512  -0.46334891  1.18450149 -1.17728558  1.27805933
  0.25943615 -1.18671214  0.96818224  0.32928086]
```

It should be split into 'av_n' number of arrays in this case it is two:

```
[-0.22609503, -0.4501512 , -0.46334891,  1.18450149, -1.17728558]
[ 1.27805933,  0.25943615, -1.18671214,  0.96818224,  0.32928086]
```

The outptut is:

```
[ 0.52598215 -0.09535753 -0.82503053  1.07634186 -0.42400236]
```

The only problem it takes quite a lot of time for my application in average 0.25 of a second, is there any faster way of doing it?

Comment: Not entirely clear what this should do. What is `divide` supposed to do? Can you show some example data (less than 40k items) and the expected results?

Comment: @tobias_k, thank you for your comment, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that `data` is evenly divisible into the desired number of sublists, you could `reshape` the array and then use `np.average` with the appropriate `axis` parameter.

```
>>> data
array([-0.22609503, -0.4501512 , -0.46334891,  1.18450149, -1.17728558,
        1.27805933,  0.25943615, -1.18671214,  0.96818224,  0.32928086])
>>> np.average(data.reshape((2, -1)), axis=0)
array([ 0.52598215, -0.09535752, -0.82503053,  1.07634186, -0.42400236])
>>> np.average(data.reshape((2, -1)), axis=1)
array([-0.22647585,  0.32964929])
```

If the list is not evenly divisible, you could trim the last few elements; you seem to do something like that in your code, too. The result is the same, and it is considerably faster.

```
>>> data = np.random.randn(127874)                             
>>> %timeit np.asarray(list(average(2, data)))
10 loops, best of 3: 36.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.average(data.reshape((2, len(data)//2)), axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop
```

(Using `list(average(...))` due to different behaviour of `map` in Python 2 vs. 3; note that your code creates a whole lot of temporary lists, including the one created by `map`.)

Comment: Wow, thank you, you have done it in a very easy and efficient manner, thank you very much!